# javascript: why is returning so much decimals? After a multiply

Tags: javascript

I have next code in javascript

```
var quantity = 12;
var import = 12.55;
var total = quantity * import;
```

total is resulting with next value: 150.60000000000002, the true result is 150.60 (use calculator)

why? itis normal in a division but in a multiply ....

I tested  in IE and Chrome, both with the same result

Comment: I used Math.round(total * 100) / 100 to get the right value

Comment: Use can total.toFixed(2) also